# Disabling remaining Buttons, On Click of one button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a small problem while disabling/enabling buttons in Swing Application.
It's a very basic problem, but  I'm  new to this concept.

I have a requirement like, having 2 buttons to perform 2 individual operations.

1. While Running initially B1 & B2 Should be Visible/Enabled.
2. If B1 Clicked, then B2 should be disabled/Invisible. After B1 work Completed, then Both B1 & B2 Should be Visible/Enabled.
3. If B2 Clicked, then B1 should be disabled/Invisible.
   After B2 work Completed, then Both B1 & B2 Should be Visible/Enabled.

But, my problem, is, after processing B1/B2 SetEnable/SetVisible is working. It should be disabled before start and enabled after completing task

Can anyone help in this case?

Below is my Code

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FinCSV implements ActionListener {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("ICON");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 4, 4));
  JButton primaryButton = new JButton(" Primary Process");
  JButton secondaryButton = new JButton(" Secondary Process");

  public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    FinCSV msql = new FinCSV();
    msql.initGUI();
  }

  public void initGUI() {
    this.primaryButton.setActionCommand("Primary");
    this.secondaryButton.setActionCommand("Secondary");
    this.primaryButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.secondaryButton.addActionListener(this);

    this.primaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
    this.secondaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));

    panel.add(this.primaryButton);
    panel.add(this.secondaryButton);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(650, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Primary")) {
         secondaryButton.setVisible(false);
        // secondaryButton.setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Primary Process");
        }
          secondaryButton.setVisible(true);
         // secondaryButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Secondary")) {
        primaryButton.setVisible(false);
         // primaryButton.setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Secondary Process");
        }
        primaryButton.setVisible(true);
      // primaryButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, what do you mean by "after processing B1/B2 SetEnable/SetVisible is working" ? Please rephrase.

Comment: @eitanfar Pressing Button #1, should set the visibility/enabled state of Button #2 to `false` and visa-versa...Yeah, I had to run the code to tweak to it to...

Comment: See [How to Use Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton).  With a third radio button for 'neither A nor B'.

Comment: BTW - the entire description is confusing me.  What exactly should happen if the user activates one of the buttons when it is enabled/visible?  Please tell us what all this does for the user as well.  For best help, we need to understand what all this is intended to **achieve,** as opposed to strictly what you are trying to **do.**

Answer (score 2):

Don't do anything that might block the Event Dispatching Thread.  The problem here is your executing a long running process within the `actionPerformed` method

```
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Primary Process");
}
//..
```

Which is preventing it from allowing the EDT from processing new paint requests (like painting the disabled button)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Consider using a `SwingWorker` to actually carry out the work and re-enabling the state when it's done.

Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FinCSV implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ICON");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 4, 4));
    JButton primaryButton = new JButton(" Primary Process");
    JButton secondaryButton = new JButton(" Secondary Process");

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        FinCSV msql = new FinCSV();
        msql.initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        this.primaryButton.setActionCommand("Primary");
        this.secondaryButton.setActionCommand("Secondary");
        this.primaryButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.secondaryButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.primaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        this.secondaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));

        panel.add(this.primaryButton);
        panel.add(this.secondaryButton);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(650, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Primary")) {
            secondaryButton.setVisible(false);
            PrimaryWorker worker = new PrimaryWorker(secondaryButton);
            worker.execute();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Secondary")) {
            primaryButton.setVisible(false);
            SecondaryWorker secondaryWorker = new SecondaryWorker(primaryButton);
            secondaryWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    public abstract class StateWorker<T, V> extends SwingWorker<T, V> {

        private JButton btn;

        public StateWorker(JButton btn) {
            this.btn = btn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            btn.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    public class PrimaryWorker extends StateWorker<Integer, Integer> {

        public PrimaryWorker(JButton btn) {
            super(btn);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Primary Process");
                sum += i;
                publish(i);
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }

    public class SecondaryWorker extends StateWorker<Integer, Integer> {

        public SecondaryWorker(JButton btn) {
            super(btn);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Secondary Process");
                sum += i;
                publish(i);
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }
}
```

See also Andrew's comment in the main comments section about using `JRadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

Keep complete code of actionPerformed in to Thread and then try

```
 Thread th1 = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
//                         Keep you code here
                    }
  };
  th1.start();
```

Comment: Beware that Swing is a single threaded environment and UI components should never be updated from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score -1):

This is because you process your for inside the main thread of your code.

If you wand to do something heavy and still you want other parts of your code run smoothly, you should use Threads.

However, for your code, you can use InvokeLater to let your main thread to run part of your code after the first available time - I think it is when you are out of every function call you have up to this call (They have to be finished and control should be back to the main running routine which I believe it is update GUI for the next cycle. Please read InvokeLater help section by yourself)

This is how your code work if you want to disable/invisible your buttons.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FinCSV implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ICON");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 4, 4));
    JButton primaryButton = new JButton(" Primary Process");
    JButton secondaryButton = new JButton(" Secondary Process");

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        FinCSV msql = new FinCSV();
        msql.initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        this.primaryButton.setActionCommand("Primary");
        this.secondaryButton.setActionCommand("Secondary");
        this.primaryButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.secondaryButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.primaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        this.secondaryButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));

        panel.add(this.primaryButton);
        panel.add(this.secondaryButton);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(650, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Primary")) {
            secondaryButton.setVisible(false);
            primaryButton.setEnabled(false);
            run_btn_1();

        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Secondary")) {
            primaryButton.setVisible(false);
            secondaryButton.setEnabled(false);
            run_btn_2();
        }
    }

    public void run_btn_1() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Primary Process");
                }
                secondaryButton.setVisible(true);
                primaryButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void run_btn_2() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("[ " + (i + 1) + " ] Inside Secondary Process");
                }
                primaryButton.setVisible(true);
                secondaryButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, all you need to do is to put something here:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your code if you want to run it in next gui update
            }
        });
```

**EDITED**

Using threads:

```
public void run_btn_1() {
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //loop
        secondaryButton.setVisible(true);
        primaryButton.setEnabled(true);

    }
}).start();
}

public void run_btn_2() {
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // loop
        primaryButton.setVisible(true);
        secondaryButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}).start();
}
```

Comment: I also disable your buttons while working so it will prevent multiple clicks on your buttons. Once you click on a button and gui is busy, then the click will be processed in next available time. So better to disable it while doing something in your main thread.

Comment: If Button is hidden then how user can click on hidden button.

Comment: `invokeLater` will only delay the problem, sure it will allow the buttons to be updated but will prevent the rest of the UI from been updated until the code exists the `run` method...you're just substituting one problem for another ...

Comment: Yeah he can use Threading as I mentioned, but as far as I understood, s/he just need to disable/hide the buttons.

It is not a rocket launcher app :)

Comment: But not disable the entire UI as well...this just leads to more bad habits.